# How can I test Joomla 3.2.1's use of custom template error.php file?

Tags: joomla, error-handling

Joomla documentation http://docs.joomla.org/Custom_error_pages indicates that if your templates/mytemplate/error.php  exists Joomla will load it instead of templates/system/error.php.
This is not happening on my site.  Is there some setting or other condition that would prevent this from happening?  I'm using the same template on another site with no problem.  Maybe a php.ini, or .htaccess setting could be causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, I'm using a small template for only the "home" Joomla link.  The entire site, with the exception of the "home" landing page is using mytemplate.  When I moved the "home" menu selection to another link which was part of the main menu, all is well.  The small template doesn't have an error.php file.  So, Joomla must correlate the "home" menu selection's template assignment to the place where it will find the error.php file.  I couldn't find any documentation to that effect.

Comment: It's really going to depend on the error, but if it is a page not found, then it's going to sue the default template ... since it isn't found it can't have been assigned a template.

Comment: @Elin Your use of the expression "default template" must indicate the "home" selection of the menu system.  That's what seems to be happening.  Thanks.

Comment: No, it refers to the template style you have selected as default in the template style manager.